# Jquery code does not work on mobile (Android)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

The div with `class = "solutions"` do not hide on load and the click event do not work. This works perfectly on my laptop but not on my mobile.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".solutions").hide();

   $("button").click(function() {
     $(this).next("div").toggle();
   });
 });
```

I have checked through the related questions and none addressed my situation.
Here is a link to the html code.

https://codepen.io/oghenebrume/pen/yjZWZv

Comment: You'll need to expand on 'does not work". Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".solutions").hide();

    $("button").on("touchstart click", function() {
        $(this).next("div").toggle();
    });
});
```

I used the above code and it now works on both devices.

Comment: omg i just realized experiencing the same what you've just got....
is this just for my android chrome problems or something else?